# DNS server not found for ip address?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, dns

for educational purposes, I removed the ip address of the dns server from my network manager options, then
I entered a website server's ip address in the url bar of google chrome,
I expected that the website will open because there is no need for DNS server any more since I didn't use a domain name!!, however google displays a message saying that DNS server not found..
So, what is going on ??!!

Answer (score 0):

http sends a URL with the request (that's how multiple domains can be served under one IP address in clouds etc...). So websites are being programmed expecting the URL and don't like to be accessed by IP so some do funny stuff. Like google redirects me back go google.com when i try to access it by IP http://172.217.0.46, yahoo shows Will be right back... at http://98.139.183.24

Answer (score 0):

Most websites contains links to other sites and serve up adds. All of these are linked via named hosts. If your browser tries to load a webpage from an IP-address, it will still have to resolve these hostnames. That is where the message of the missing DNS comes from.

As @meccooll already mentioned, some sites expect to be called by "name" and not by IP-address. At my work I've set up a server that hosts 40 different sites: All these sites have the same IP-address, but a different hostname. If you access the server by its IP-address, I made it to display a webpage, listing all the sites it hosts.

Today, I was also working on a new server, that doesn't have an an entry in the DNS servers at work (yet). The only way to access this server is via its IP address.